# C# Chart assign String value to Axis Y

Tags: c#, charts, data-visualization

I'm building a chart that is meant to receive string values in the Y axis and int values in the X Axis.
So far I have been using the Series AddXY method to try and assign the values to the corresponding Axis, but after the values are added the Chart only has X  values(All Y's are 0).

Is there a way to Assign string to the Y axis and set a corresponding X value?

Comment: What charttype do you use? For normal types you really numeric (or datetime) need y-values, or else where would the chart datapoints go?? You can still assign a string to the datapoint Label. Or do you use Bars? These have X- and Y-Axis switched.. It often helps to show an image of how the chart should look like!

Comment: I have an object with the following structure, Day, Time . The values in the Y Axis will be Times (09:15, 15:53) and the values in the X Axis will be the days of a month (1,2,3,4,5). I need to assign the days of a month to the Times for a list of objects.

Comment: So the values are not really strings but times! Again: What charttype do you use?

Comment: Yes the Y values are times, but without the dates of couse. The chart type is a LineChart.

Comment: Good. So make sure to add the X- and y-values as the correct types. Adding string will result in zero-values. Best tell the Series about the [chartvaluetypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartvaluetype?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Yes, Setting my YValueType to Time alowed for the times to show up in the Y axis, thanks! I guess strings only belong to the X-Axis!

Comment: Yes, strings __sometimes__ make sense for the x-axis, like when they are IDs, StateCodes, Names etc..

Comment: Follow up question. If I have a List of dates in my X axis but i miss a day (14/3,15/3,17/3) the date is still shown in the graph  as my X interval is 1, is there a way to not represent the date or just dont draw the line? Thanks.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Space allowing (!!!) all labels should show.